# Download, install, and run Android App that is not available in my country

Tags: applications, google-play-store, apk, android-auto

I am actually interested to download certain apps from Play Store. However, the app that I wanted to download (in this case, Android Auto) is not available in my country.

Previously, I managed to download the APK from some third party site and installed on my phone. Initially, everything works fine (able to run on my vehicle and even on my phone), but recently Google seems to prohibit usage of this app (not sure why, possibly due to change in policy). My question is, how do I able to use this app that is not available on my country? Detailed steps are appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried an app named floater? It basically fakes your GPS location. http://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-fake-your-location-on-android-no-root/

Comment: I am not sure about that though. I will try it out. My only worry is that it is based on my account's billing address. But I do not want to change this address every time I use this app.

Answer (score 0):

### **You could use a different store to download the app**

First, you will need to enable Unknown Sources ( To install apps from outside the Play Store )

- Open Settings
- Open Security
- Click or Tick (Allow Unknown Sources)
- Accept the disclaimer

### **Now you can install Apps from the internet, it's time to install Android Auto for your device**

- Find if your device is either ARM, ARM 64, Etc...
- Download and install Android Auto

( I would suggest APK Mirror because of how hard it is to put fake software on their )

It's as if they check if your app has ever been on the play store first, And if it hasn't been it won't be added to their site ! ( i think, but I'm not sure )

[AndroidAuto on APKMirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-auto/android-auto-2-2-7108-release/#downloads)

Answer (score 0):

There's two part to this problem.

**First, you must get the APK.** You can get it through [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/) or [APKPure](https://www.apkpure.com/).

Then, even if you have the APK, the app itself might detect your country through client-side means or server-side means and still block your usage of the application. If this is the case, then you might require either an older version of the APK, a modified version of the APK, to fake your location, to use a VPN, or, if it's server-side, you might not be able to use it at all.

Because you mentioned Google, I'm pretty sure they just get your Google account's country and block your usage with that, so there might be nothing to do after all. You can always create a new Google Account for another country, but it's not guaranteed to work and you'll have to re-purchase everything again.

Comment: And perhaps use a VPN to outsmart google to think that you are logging in from another country?

Comment: @papakias If it is Google, they probably just look at the country to which the Google account is linked. When you create a Google account, you must input your country in two places, and one of them is automatically determined by your location. Creating a new Google account using a VPN might actually work, however, if the usage of the location-tracking app is locked, then maybe even an US citizen might not be able to use it outside of the permitted areas.